# How to join three entities in one table using spring jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to join three entities (table) using spring-jpa into one table using Many-To-Many relationship.

Three classes are :

1] User

2] Resource

3] Privilege

And I want to combine these three entities into one User_Resource_Privilege table

### User Entity

```
package com.****.acl.domain;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {

@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="user_id", nullable=false, length=40)
private String userId;

@Column(name="user_name", nullable=false, length=45)
private String userName;

@Column(name="first_name", nullable=true, length=45)
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name", nullable=true, length=45)
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email", nullable=true, length=50)
private String email;

public User(){

}

public User(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;       
}


getter and setters .......
}
```

### Resource Entity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class Resource {

@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="resource_id", nullable=false, length=40)
private String resourceId;

@Column(name="resource_name", nullable=false, length=45)
private String name;

@Column(name="resource_type", nullable=false, length=45)
private String type;

public Resource(){

}

public Resource(String name, String type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

getter and setter ......
}
```

### Privilege Entity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class Privilege {

@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="privilege_id", nullable=false, length=40)
private String privilegeId;

@Column(name="resource_name", nullable=false, length=45)
private String name;

@Column(name="resource_description", nullable=true, length=45)
private String description;

public Privilege(){

}

getters and setters ....
}
```

Now I want to create one table by joining all the three entities described above.

The join in ER diagram:

[image]

Can someone please help me in joining these three tables using Many-To-Many relationship and let me know how to achieve this using spring-jpa and REST ?
Also it will be great if you please explain how to insert data in this "User_Resource_Privilege" table using REST/curl command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is make an embeddable ID and wrap it with the class. You can afterwards even expand this wrapper class to hold other fields.

[java geeks example of embedded id](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-embeddedid-example/)

You would get something like

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedIdClass implements Serializable {
  private String userId;
  private String resourceId;
  private String privilegeId;

// constructors, getters and setters, equals, etc
}

@Entity
public class Wrapper {
  @EmbeddedId
  private EmbeddedIdClass id;

// constructors, etc
}
```

Instead of just using the strings in this example, you should use the complete objects and let hibernate (or something like it) do it's stuff. It should only take the id's into the database and do it's magic itself.

edit:
Just wanting to insert the id's as values, but keeping relationships would look something like this

```
@Entity
public class Wrapper {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private User user;
  private Resource resource;
  private Privilege privilege;


// constructors
  public Wrapper(final User user, final Resource resource, final Privilege privilege) {
    this.user = user;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.privilege = privilege;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does this create any relationship between the tables ? or is it just creating one primary key ? Because I looking for inserting the values in this join table in mySql database

Comment: If you use the object version instead of the string version, you will get primary keys with the values inserted. If you only want to insert the values, generate a separate PK and use the objects themselves as fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this solution and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi, I am able to create table and its working fine. Just struggling with insertion part. How would you insert data in the joining table ? If I have userId, resourceId and privilegeId how can I insert row in UserResourcePrivilege table ? Please help.

Comment: As you are using JPA, you only have to create a new UserResourcePriviledge object and persist it. You have created this object with the classes, then you construct your object with the objects you want to couple together

Comment: I am able to insert object in mysql table. I just didnt use relationship constraint. I am gonna handle relationship while adding the object using JPA. I used your first solution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are these 2 solutions? I tried Wrapper with objects, but does it not need annotations @ManyToMany etc? Should User contain Set<Resources>, etc?